# DAL classes generater using DAAB or ado.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, daab

I am using enterprise library DAAB with 4 layers

User interface layer, custom type layer, business logic layer, data access layer.

I want to remain in 4 layers please guide is there any preferably free/ open source code generater that can generate my DAL classes. Or some way to generte DAL using simple ado.net ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out Entity Framework (part of .NET 4.0)? :) It can generate DAL classes based on your existing database structure. And it's free.

Comment: Gan thanks,

I will check it as have not checked it already. Can we use Entity Framework (which is part of 4.0) with framework 3.5 ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, have not tried that before, but possible i guess. Or you can use the Entity Framework that first comes with .NET 3.5 SP1. See more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework

Comment: Also, if you are looking for open source way, you can have a look at NHibernate. It's one of the most popular way to create your DAL.